# Why does python not provide output in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
def prepareData(dataset):
    X,y=[],[]
    for words in dataset:
        X.append([features(untag(dataset), s) for s in range(len(dataset))])
        y.append([tag for word,tag in sentences])
    return X,y
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Here, `dataset` is a list and `s` is an integer value index of any object in the list.

Comment: Please improve your formatting, and provide more details.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
y.append([tag for word,tag in sentences])
```

You don't tell us what `sentences` is, but it's apparent it's not what it needs to be.

For example:

```
sentences = ['this is a test','a quick brown fox']
[tag for word,tag in sentences]

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

If your `sentences` was a list of two-tuples the code would work:

```
sentences = [('this is a test','tag1'),('a quick brown fox','tag2')]
In [15]: [tag for word,tag in sentences]
Out[15]: ['tag1', 'tag2']
```